# Formatting as.Date in R: Ambiguous Format and Leading Zeroes

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to format a column of data from a CSV file into a date in R.

Examples of elements in this column are "6182012" and "12102013", for June 18, 2012 and December 10, 2013, respectively. They have the integer type, and are of the format `[month, without leading zeros][day][year]`.

However, I just can't seem to get R to recognize the date. I've tried:

```
 >>> date.int <- 6182012
 >>> as.Date(date.int, format="%m%d%Y")
      Error in charToDate(x) : 
            character string is not in a standard unambiguous format 
 >>> as.Date(as.character(date.int), format="%m%d%Y")
      NA
```

I'm not sure why the first attempt doesn't use the format string that I pass it, and instead attempts to use the standard date formats. I assume this is a type issue.

My best guess as to why the second attempt doesn't work is that none of the months have leading zeros ("6" and not "06"), while the dates all do.

My question is: is there an easy way to pass `as.Date` a format string that takes this into account?

EDIT: I just figured out the solution, and I'll post it just in case someone else runs into this problem (the data is FEC contribution data, so I assume somebody will).

I think the problem was not having a leading zero for months, so I just added one:

```
add.zero <- function(dt) {
    if (nchar(dt) == 7){
        return(paste("0", dt, sep=""))
    } else {
        return(dt)
    }
}
add.zero(as.character(date.int))
# or, if you have a vector of dates
dates.formatted <- unlist(lapply(dates, add.zero))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date.int <- c(6182012, 12102013)
```

In the above `date.int`, the number of digits are different (7 & 8).  Inorder to make the number of digits the same across all elements, you can use `formatC` or `sprintf` to paste a leading `0` when ever the element is short of 8 digits.  Here, we are using `sprintf`.

```
as.Date(sprintf("%08d", date.int), '%m%d%Y')
#[1] "2012-06-18" "2013-12-10"
```

Comment: Awesome. Way simpler than the solution I came up with. Thanks!

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, I will add some text

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of other ways to format the strings

```
x <- c(6182012, 12102013)
as.Date(chartr(" ", "0", format(x, FALSE)), "%m%d%Y")
# [1] "2012-06-18" "2013-12-10"
as.Date(formatC(x, 8, 0, "d", 0), "%m%d%Y")
# [1] "2012-06-18" "2013-12-10"
```